# Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?

Tags: root, gksu, wayland

I installed Ubuntu 17.10. Now I am having trouble with `gksu`:

```
$ gksu -dg synaptic
No ask_pass set, using default!
xauth: /tmp/libgksu-HgUjgQ/.Xauthority
STARTUP_ID: gksu/synaptic/8760-0-alex-XPS-15-9530_TIME4974977
cmd[0]: /usr/bin/sudo
cmd[1]: -H
cmd[2]: -S
cmd[3]: -p
cmd[4]: GNOME_SUDO_PASS
cmd[5]: -u
cmd[6]: root
cmd[7]: --
cmd[8]: synaptic
buffer: -GNOME_SUDO_PASS-
brute force GNOME_SUDO_PASS ended...
Yeah, we're in...
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(synaptic:8767): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1
xauth: /tmp/libgksu-HgUjgQ/.Xauthority
xauth_env: (null)
dir: /tmp/libgksu-HgUjgQ
```

If I don't use `-g`, the password dialog is disabled. So looks like a problem with creating a tty for root.

Any advice?

Comment: `gksudo` won't work in a [Wayland session](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451), you may [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/q/961304/) and try.

Comment: The error itself if an X error "cannot open display: :1". Wayland is designed this way and, in the opinion of the developers, you should not be running graphical applications as root from the command line. You can work around with xhost.

Comment: `gksu -dg synaptic`  You never should be doing that anyways.

Comment: @N0rbert stop adding the [tag:17.10] to questions which mention 17.10. Version tags are to be used if the question is specific to that release. Most of these questions are generally applicable wherever Wayland, GNOME Shell, etc. are available, and that includes past and future versions.

Comment: @maru. 16.04 LTS is current, 17.04 is near EOL, so normal 17.10 means Wayland and default GNOME Shell, so [17.10 tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/17.10) is useful, I think. It is [difficult to find questions, where users have problems with 17.10, but have no answers and comments here](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=17.10%20-%5b17.10%5d%20%09is%3aquestion). They need answers, but forgot to add 17.10 tag when asked. I can stop adding tag. It was a goodwill.

Answer (score 60):

### Note this answer is specific to versions of Ubuntu using Wayland, 17.10 being the first release to use Wayland by default.

It is a feature not a bug! It is a design feature of Wayland that you can not start graphical applications as root from the terminal.

The main discussions are of course on the Fedora sites. See [Fedora bug #1274451](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451) and [Graphical applications can't be run as root in wayland (e.g. gedit, beesu, gparted, nautilus) on Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/102936/graphical-applications-cant-be-run-as-root-in-wayland-eg-gedit-beesu-gparted-nautilus/). But there is some discussion on the Ubuntu sites as well ([Ubuntu Devs Uncertain about Using Wayland by Default in 17.10 - OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/ubuntu-uncertain-using-wayland-default)).

Ubuntu bug report: [Unable to launch pkexec'ed applications on Wayland session](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1713313)

**Potential work around** - If you are editing system files with a graphical editor (such as gedit) use a command line tool such as `nano` or `vim` or `emacs`. `nano` is typically easier for new users, `vim` is more powerful and has more features, see [this Vim Tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/vim-tutorial) or similar.

At any rate , if you really want or need to **run graphical apps as root**, set `xhost` first which forces fallback to Xserver.

To set permissions run:

```
xhost si:localuser:root
```

When you are finished, to remove permissions

```
xhost -si:localuser:root
```

You can add a graphical / desktop option to do this as per [this synaptic bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1712089)

> pkexec'ed applications may be healed with `xhost +si:localuser:root` placed in XDG autostart as follows (N0rbert's idea):
>
> ```
> cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/xdg/autostart/xhost.desktop
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=xhost
> Comment=Fix graphical root applications
> Exec="xhost +si:localuser:root"
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> EOF
> ```

You could add this xhost command to .bashrc, but I would advise a pair of aliases

```
alias gsuon='xhost si:localuser:root'

alias gsuoff='xhost -si:localuser:root'
```

You can name the aliases whatever you wish.

For details see:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1713313
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nmap/+bug/1713311
- [Arch Wiki: Running X apps as root](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_X_apps_as_root#Wayland)
- [Arch Wiki: Xhost](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost)
- [What are xhost and xhost +si?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877820/what-are-xhost-and-xhost-si)

---

## Switch back to Xorg

If you prefer Xorg for any reason, you can select to run on Xorg at login

See [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Does this workaround work [with Mir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817902/unable-to-open-any-graphical-app-with-sudo) as well?

Comment: I do not know about MIR, it may.

Comment: Or just `xhost +local:`

Comment: @chaskes Less secure , but sure

Comment: Great answer :-) Please fix typo: alias gsuoff='-si:localuser:root'  --> alias gsuoff='xhost -si:localuser:root'

Comment: "It is a feature not a bug !"... sigh. These kind of things is exactly reason I cannot convince  my friend and colleagues to switch to linux. Using VIM and Nano is not an alternatives to GEdit. Gedit works like notepad, while you need to learn CRTL-code for those others. And take for instance Nano using the terms like "Write Out" instead of "Save".... Very user unfriendly.

Comment: This also completely breaks gparted, which is kinda an important thing to have access to. What ever happened to "Do not try to prevent stupid people from doing stupid things; you will only succeed in preventing clever people from doing clever things."?

Comment: @MatthewNajmon - Try the work around and file a bug report. Otherwise, this is not really the place to complain about the problem.

Comment: As of Feb 15, the "xhost" command allowed gksu "deja-dup --backup" to work. As of Mar 29, it no longer works. The password prompt is given but the graphic no longer accepts the password. It goes into the terminal running the gksu command in plain text.

Comment: It is better to just type **sudo -EH application** instead of nasty xhost hack. xhost is opening X wrapper for root access and this is insecure. If an application is written against Wayland API, like gedit for example, it would be better to run it as **sudo -EH gedit**. The switch -E preserves the env variables (like WAYLAND_DISPLAY) and this is the trick

Comment: _use a command line tool_ – and call it like `sudoedit myfile` instead of `sudo whatever-editor myfile`

Comment: The ubuntu wiki also says that: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland, yet I can run gtk apps in ubuntu on wayland just fine with sudo. Why?

Comment: This so-called "feature" also breaks e.g. the Matlab Linux installer. It is truly a bug for some workflows, even if it is a "feature" for a majority.

Answer (score 23):

## [image] Solutions

In Wayland it is often difficult to run GUI application programs with elevated (sudo -H, gksu ...) permissions. It is a good idea to do such tasks with command line tools.

But there are workarounds, if you have a GUI tool, that works well for you and needs elevated permissions. (I use two such standard tools: the Synaptic Package Manager, **`synaptic`** and the partitioning tool Gparted, **`gparted`**. I use MakeUSB to create USB boot drives, **`mkusb`**, too, but it can run the parts that need elevated permissions without graphics.)

#### gvfs admin backend

**The gvfs admin backend is a good tool for elevated permissions with GUI tools.** In Ubuntu 17.10 (gvfs >= 1.29.4) and newer versions you can use the gvfs admin backend. Notice that you need the full path, for example

```
thunar admin:///path/to/directory
gedit admin:///path/to/file
```

In theory, the gvfs admin backend method (which uses polkit) is better and safer (than `xhost` and `sudo -H`), regardless of the UI you use.

You don't run the whole application as root. Privilege escalation happens only when strictly necessary. See the following link and links from it,

- [sisco311's reply in the Ubuntu Forums thread 'Which best practice for using gedit as root?'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385818&p=13743162#post13743162)

  This is post #4. See also post #6 in the same thread.

#### `xhost` and `sudo -H`

1. There is a workaround to allow graphical application programs owned by other users than the logged in user in Wayland,

   ```
    xhost +si:localuser:root
   ```
2. `gksu` and `gksudo` are not bundled with standard Ubuntu and do not work here, but they work in Xorg.

   Instead you can use

   ```
    sudo -H
   ```

   **Edit:**

   [**-H** is no longer necessary (in 20.04 LTS and newer versions)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463801&p=14044344#post14044344)

   > Prior to 20.04 (or maybe 19.10, I can't remember when) using sudo for
   > a GUI application, particularly the file manager, could change
   > ownership of files and folders in your home to root, completely
   > removing your ability to login to the system as user. Changes to the
   > way the system uses sudo means that the danger of that happening has
   > now gone so it should be safe as far as that problem is concerned.

   **end of edit**
3. It is a good idea to prevent graphical application programs owned by other users than the logged in user afterwards,

   ```
    xhost -si:localuser:root
   ```

#### nautilus-admin

It is also possible to use `nautilus-admin` for file operations with elevated permissions and to use `gedit` with elevated permissions. This is described in the following AskUbuntu answer,

- [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882)

### Temporary access for root to the Wayland desktop via function `gks`

Please avoid `sudo GUI-program`. It can cause the system to overwrite the configuration files for your regular user ID with `root`'s configuration and set ownership and permissions to fit `root` and lock out your regular user ID.  You should run GUI applications with `sudo -H`, which writes the configuration files in `root`'s home directory `/root`. Example:

```
sudo -H gedit myfile.txt
```

But there is a risk that you forget `-H`. Instead you can create a function, for example `gks`

```
gks () { xhost +si:localuser:root; sudo -H "$@"; xhost -si:localuser:root; }
```

and store it in your `~/.bashrc` near the aliases. Then you can run

```
gks gedit myfile.txt
```

in a way similar to how you used `gksudo` before.

### Testing

You can check how `sudo`, `sudo -H` and `gks` work with the following commands

```
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ sudo bash -c "echo ~"
/home/sudodus
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ sudo -H bash -c "echo ~"
/root
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ gks () { xhost +si:localuser:root; sudo -H "$@"; xhost -si:localuser:root; }
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ gks bash -c "echo ~"
localuser:root being added to access control list
/root
localuser:root being removed from access control list
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $
```

and of course

```
gks gedit myfile.txt
```

according to the example in the previous section.

### Method that works via Alt-F2 and Gnome Shell menu

Instead of adding a simple one-line function to `~/.bashrc`, you can make a system, that works also without bash. It may be convenient to use, but is more complicated to set up. Please notice that you should install only one of the alternatives, because the one-line function will disturb using this more complicated system.

### Three files

The shellscript **`gks`**:

```
#!/bin/bash

xhost +si:localuser:root

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  xterm -T "gks console - enter command and password" \
  -fa default -fs 14 -geometry 60x4 \
  -e bash -c 'echo "gks lets you run command lines with GUI programs
with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland."; \
read -p "Enter command: " cmd; \
cmdfile=$(mktemp); echo "$cmd" > "$cmdfile"; \
sudo -H bash "$cmdfile"; rm "$cmdfile"'
else
 xterm -T "gks console - enter password" -fa default -fs 14 -geometry 60x4 -e sudo -H "$@"
fi 

xhost -si:localuser:root;
```

The desktop file **`gks.desktop`**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Categories=Application;System;
Type=Application
Name=gks
Description=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
Comment=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
Exec=gks %f
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gks.svg
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
GenericName[en_US.UTF-8]=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
```

The icon file **`gks.svg`** looks like this:

[image]

You can download the icon file or a tarball with all three files from this link,

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland/gks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland/gks)

Copy the [extracted or copied & pasted] files to the following locations,

```
sudo cp gks /usr/bin
sudo cp gks.desktop /usr/share/applications/
sudo cp gks.svg /usr/share/icons
```

Logout/login or reboot, and there should be a working desktop icon. It will work from a terminal window like with the simple solution with the function.

**<kbd>Alt F2</kbd>** box:

[image]

Gnome Shell menu:

[image]

gks console and gparted:

[image]

### Custom script and desktop file

If you have only a few GUI applications, that need elevated permissions, you could make custom scripts and desktop files for them and avoid entering the command (application name). You would only enter the password, which is not more difficult compared to the previous versions of Ubuntu (you should enter the password anyway).

Example with the simple GUI program `xlogo` that comes with the program package `x11-apps`:

The shellscript **`gkslogo`** (simplified compared to `gks`),

```
#!/bin/bash

xhost +si:localuser:root

xterm -T "gks console - enter password" -fa default -fs 14 -geometry 60x4 -e sudo -H xlogo

xhost -si:localuser:root;
```

The desktop file **`gkslogo.desktop`**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Categories=Application;System;
Type=Application
Name=gkslogo
Description=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
Comment=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
Exec=gkslogo
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gks.svg
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
GenericName[en_US.UTF-8]=Run program with temporary elevated permissions in Wayland
```

I was lazy and used the same icon file **`gks.svg`**

Copy the [copied & pasted] files to the following locations,

```
sudo cp gkslogo /usr/bin
sudo cp gkslogo.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

gks[logo] console and xlogo:

[image]

Comment: Is the "Temporary access for root to the Wayland desktop via function gks" a safer method (e.g. than adding a file like `/etc/xdg/autostart/xhost.destop` as also suggested) because it ends by restoring the original environment? And can we safely replace `sudo -H` with `gksu` in the alias so as to use insert into .desktop files, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I would think it is safer to allow root access to the desktop only when necessary. And yes, you can replace `sudo -H` with `gksu` in the function, it may work better for your applications.

Comment: How to do in case Alt-F2 or Gnome Shell menu?

Comment: @AlexChapiro, I enjoyed modifying this method for Alt-F2 and the Gnome Shell menu :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I'll test it more later, but at the first glance all the problems had been resolved.

Comment: I tried replacing `sudo -H` with `gksu` in the function, but it didn't work, which should have been expected; so it seems there's no way of escaping from the use of terminal ;-)

Comment: @Sadi, You are right, It does *not* work to replace `sudo -H` with `gksu` in the function. There is a complaint "Unable to copy the .Xauthority file". I tested in Xorg, where `gksu` and `gksudo` work, hoping that the copied file would somehow survive after logout and login to Wayland, but no.

Comment: @Sadi, However, you can use terminal in an implicit way with the second method using the shellscript and desktop file. If you have only a few GUI applications, that need elevated permissions, you could make custom scripts and desktop files for them and avoid entering the command (application name). You would only enter the password, which is not more difficult compared to `gksu`.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I think Alt+F2 way represents the closest eqivalent to the obsolete method that we are missing now, and thank you for this :-) @AlexChapiro , I highly recommend this to be marked as the answer ;-)

Comment: +1 for extremely thorough answer. Similar to your `gks` abbreviation I had setup `gsu` to use policy kits (the new future for `16.04`) for `gedit` and `nautilus`. When 18.04 comes out though I think I'll just name the `xhost +si...` wrapper script `gksu` which I'll never install from packages starting with `18.04`.

Comment: "Wayland is designed to not allow elevated (sudo -H, gksu ...) permissions with GUI application programs."  -- false.  Wayland allows root applications just fine.  You can see this by running `sudo -E gedit`.  There is currently a bug in `gdm` where it configures the Xwayland X11 compatibility server to not support XAUTHORITY, which is required for X11 applications running as root to work.  Native wayland applications running as root work just fine.

Comment: @psusi, I modified the answer to avoid statements about the design and intentions of Wayland.

Answer (score 6):

Better check whether wayland is really running first before granting root right

```
if [ $XDG_SESSION_TYPE = "wayland" ]; then
    xhost +si:localuser:root
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **Ubuntu 17.04** or higher, it is recommended to use the *gvfs admin backend*. Simply add **admin://** to the front of the full filepath you want to open in an app like the *Text Editor* or the *Files apps*.

For instance, to change boot settings, open

```
admin:///etc/default/grub
```

This method uses PolicyKit and will still work with Ubuntu 17.10's Wayland default, while sudo and gksu for GUI apps won't.

Comment: Thanks. For me this worked best with **gedit** (except a strange behavior when used simply as `gedit admin:`), very oddly with **nautilus** (almost useless), and totally failed with **synaptic**. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not going to work with synaptic. It should work fine in nautilus though, but you need to pick a directory not a file like `admin:///etc/`

Comment: It kind-of works with *nautilus* but you'll see what I mean ("very oddly", "almost useless") even when you directly open a directory, and start trying to do this and that ;-)

Comment: @Sadi I have no idea what "this and that" is. You could file a bug if it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 3):

For applications which use su-to-root and pkexec you may want to add this code to `/etc/xdg/autostart` (see [my comment at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1713313/comments/3)) at your own risk:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/xdg/autostart/xhost.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xhost
Comment=Fix graphical root applications
Exec="xhost +si:localuser:root"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EOF
```

Other root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311) ).

---

If you do not want permanent solution, you may use @ravery's method:

> just type `xhost +si:localuser:root` in the terminal before launching  privileged application

Answer (score 1):

If an application support Wayland API you can run it as root using `sudo -EH application` command.

The -E switch tells sudo to preserve environment variables (as well as WAYLAND_SOCKET and XDG_RUNTIME_DIR) needed to wayland applications. It is always better to use this option over nasty xhost hack proposed in other answers. xhost allows the application to run from under X wrapper which is less secure than using Wayland (shared clipboard, keylogging etc). The sudo -EH trick wont work with an application that hadn't been rewritten for wayland, like gparted for example, but would work with gedit etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following code almost works:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e 
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Application is not specified" ;  exit
fi 
if [ $XDG_SESSION_TYPE = "wayland" ]; then
    if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
       xhost +si:localuser:root
       sudo -u root "$@"
       xhost  -  
       exit 0
    fi 
fi
gksu "$@"
```

(please excuse me for naive style of bash coding- I'm  a sort of newbie
 with this subject). T doesn't work  stable from Alt-F2, if last selection was not a terminal; in this case we just cannot set focus to  password dialog  Looks like it works from Gnome menu. Anyway<
1. It is not a 100% solution.
2. It seems to me that Ubuntu architects think that we are not supposed to search any work arounds..

Comment: I think you want `"$@"` (instead of `"$1" "$2" ...`).

Comment: Yes of course :-) These are just traces of my experiments

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [Thomas Guyot-Sionnest's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596468/134513).

I feel like this deserves its own answer, since it very simple and cleaned up so many issues for me. Create a shell script called `wlsudo` with the following contents:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 & sudo DISPLAY=:1 "$@"
```

Save it in a directory on your `$PATH`, and give it executable permissions (`chmod +x ./wlsudo`).
You should then be able to launch GUI apps using `wlsudo` in place of `sudo` in Wayland, e.g. `wlsudo synaptic` *just works*.