# sudo: No protocol specified in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, sudo, 17.10

I updated to Ubuntu 17.10. Hardware is working perfect and the only issue I found is that I try to edit files with atom like this:

```
sudo atom ~/Downloads/my_text_file.txt
```

and I get

```
No protocol specified
```

Under 16.04 I didn't have that issue. What can be the problem?

Edit: I switched to xorg as suggested and the issue persists.

Comment: Many root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311) ). You should try to migrate back to Xorg.

Comment: my solution was to edit .bashrc and paste this https://askubuntu.com/a/962782/746956