# How can I edit apache settings file on 17.10?

Tags: server, apache2, gedit

I've installed 17.10 , php7 and apache2 via apt. I'm not able to edit the apache files to use an specific directory to use the files. I've tried

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
but it returned:

`No protocol specified
Unable to init server: No se pudo conectar: Conexión rehusada
(gedit:2064): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0`

I've also tried using `sudo -s` and the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see: [Why don't gksu/gksudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-work-with-wayland)

> It is a feature not a bug ! It is a design feature of Wayland that you
>   can not start graphical applications as root from the terminal.

The solution is to edit the file with a non-GUI application, such as:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Or, alternatively:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: Note: nano is much easier for new users in general than vim, vim is IMO more powerful and has more features - https://linuxconfig.org/vim-tutorial

Comment: @Panther Drat! I should have included emacs!