# Can't install Xampp nor Lamp

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, xampp

I'm a newbbie on Ubuntu, and I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get Xampp or Lamp to work.

So I started trying to get Xampp, and I downloaded version 7.1.10, and I did everything I'm supposed to do: 
-ran chmod +x on the .run file, then I ran the file. The thing is, it installed in terminal(no interface opened like I saw in many videos), still, the installation ran smoothly. In the end, it said the setup completed sucessfully, and I went looking for the app everywhere but to no avail. I searched online but couldn't find anything that solved the problem.

So I uninstalled and installed several times, never worked.

Then I turned to Lamp. Again, setup the same way, thru terminal, in the end it even asked if I wanted to launch bitnami lamp stack, but then nothing happened. 
Again, no app, nothing.

So, any help would be greatly apreciated!(I'm running Ubuntu 17.10, maybe that's the problem somehow?)

Answer (score 0):

`Xampp` would usually get installed in `/opt/lampp` directory. Did you check the location?

Looks like it is related to this [Why don't gksu/gksudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961967/611441)

That's why you won't get the GUI.

But you can still use command line to manage it.

`cd` to `/opt/lampp` and use commands `sudo ./xampp start` and `sudo ./xampp stop`. You get list of possible commands with `./xampp`

Comment: Ye, all the files were there. But I couldn't open the xampp control panel, because there was no app.

Comment: Try and use command line

Answer (score 0):

Since 17.10 (Artful) version of Ubuntu, some applications seem to not work because of the "Wayland" server display. You may switch between Wayland/Xorg to make them work.
This article explain in details how to : [Installing and running XAMPP comfortably on Ubuntu 17.10](https://busy.org/utopian-io/@mciszczon/en-installing-and-running-xampp-comfortably-on-ubuntu-17-10)