# How to run Wireshark on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, wireshark

I used to run wireshark on ubuntu 17.04 with

```
~/$ sudo wireshark
```

but now (just after update to 17.10) when I write the same I get an error

```
~/$ sudo wireshark

    QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
    Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyQXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question due to [special circumstances of Wireshark](/a/969173/175814).

Answer (score 11):

work around

```
~$ xhost +si:localuser:root
~$ sudo wireshark
```

[Why don't gksu/gksudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-work-with-wayland/968219)

Comment: Other root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311) ).

Answer (score 7):

Really you do not need to launch WireShark as root. Please read [official page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges).

In brief you should do:

```
sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo chmod o-rx /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
```

Then log-out and log-in again.