# Putty ssh client fails with Segmentation fault after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: sudo, 17.10, putty

`sudo putty` fails with:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(putty:2153): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

putty fails with

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I uninstalled and purged putty.
After reinstalling the errors remain.

Comment: First, there is NO REASON to run PuTTy as root !!! . Just run putty as your regular user.  Second see https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961975#961975

Comment: @Panther Only tried it as root to see if I could get something more than the Segmentation Fault error message.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTy requires the Xorg options to be selected when logging in.  Answer was detailed in:

[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Thanks