# unable to launch sublime text 3 as sudo in 17.10 from terminal. No Error is shown but can be launched by typing simply subl

Tags: command-line, sudo, 17.10, sublime-text

I have installed sublime text 3 using official website [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt). I can launch it from searching and clicking on sublime icon as well as from terminal just by typing subl. But nothing is working when I type

```
> sudo subl [some file name]
```

No error nothing is being displayed. How to resolve this? I have ubuntu 17.10

I am trying

```
> gksudo subl ~/.bashrc 
Unable to copy user's Xauthrisation file
```

Comment: This doesn't address your problem but is relevant nevertheless: You should always use `gksudo` or rather `kdesudo` to start graphical programs, `sudo` is just for the command line.

Comment: What does `which subl` show? Did you try `gksudo /full/path/to/subl`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it but it was working fine in earlier versions

Comment: Now I am trying to run 
> gksudo subl ~./basrch
I am getting this error

Failed to run subl '/home/brij/.bashrc' as user root.

Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.
and also after giving the full path of sublime, same error is occuring

Comment: If you want to add information relevant to the question, please always [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/971678/edit) your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Are you running Xorg or Wayland? If Wayland, I think you are affected by the issue that is discussed and solved in the thread of this question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w

Comment: @sudodus I don't know. I have just freshly installed ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Run this command to check: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`: It will reply `wayland` or `x11`.

Comment: It is saying wayland.

Comment: Then you can try to use the link in my first comment in order to solve your problem. There are several solutions and workarounds. I wrote one answer with two methods,  a simple function and a more complicated shellscript + desktop file + icon file. Some of the other answers are similar and some answers are different. Use the method that works best for you. Good luck :-)