# Gparted automatically crashes

Tags: partitioning, gparted, 17.10, crash

When i attempted to launch gparted, it crashes and prints follwing on console. any idea to get rid of that?

Thanks in advance!

```
$ sudo gparted
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/boot-efi.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/home.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/media-supun-Data.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:5820): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Removed /run/systemd/system/-.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/boot-efi.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/home.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/media-supun-Data.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount.
```

Comment: I think that there is no specified protocol and for that reason it cannot open the display/GUI. Try "sudo apt purge gparted && sudo apt install gparted" (without the quotes). "sudo apt purge <package>" deletes the package and its files permanently & "sudo apt install <package>" installs the package.

Comment: @pomsky you are correct!, that was the problem! cheers!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup pomsky, you are correct!!!
Thanks!

[Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

```
xhost si:localuser:root 
sudo gparted
xhost -si:localuser:root
```