# Failed to connect to Mir

Tags: 16.04, mir

Eveyrtime when I'm trying to run any graphical software as root it won't work (i.e Synaptic, gedit) and I get this error :

```
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(synaptic:32380): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0`
```

I also tried running `sudo -H` and I get the same error, I executed `export DISPLAY=:0` again, absolutely nothing.

I tried using `gksudo` instead of `sudo` too, no result.

I was thinking in reinstalling Mir, but how? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What environment are you running these commands under? What terminal app? It seems like some configuration was likely broken on your system.

Comment: I just freshed installed Ubuntu, I'm using the GNOME terminal

Comment: But Mir is officially dead cannonical was using it but they abandoned it and start using Wayland

Comment: Soooo, if I download Wayland, will Synaptic, gedit, etc etc going to work as root?

Comment: @sticsk Not at all recommended, but you should be able to make them work as root under Wayland following this: [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

Comment: @pomsky It's working, I installed Wayland, I did that `xhost` thing and it's working. But do I need to remove the permissions everytime when I'm done using graphical softwares as root?