# How to use synaptic-pkexec?

Tags: synaptic

I assume this (synaptic-pkexec) was installed with a recent upgrade? The question is, how do i use it?

When i run it, i'm presented with a banner:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
```

(in red)
and then:

```
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
```

and then a numbered list of user's names, several ","s (i assume missing GECOS information) and then the username.

If i select the number for me, i get a password prompt. Enter password and then:

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

(to whom?)

How do i configure `polkit-agent-helper-1` (or something else?) to "authorize [sic]" myself?
And i'd like to run it as non-root as well.
I'll be sticking with regular synaptic for now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

Comment: synaptic-pkexec is how the "regular" synaptic has been run for quite some time. So your issues are local & not from pkexec per se. (- You can always run synaptic without root however package removal or install will not be possible. How about mentioning what release of Ubuntu or *buntu you are using..

Comment: @N0rbert It doesn't say anywhere in the question that the OP is using Wayland or 17.10.

Comment: Dear OP could you please shade more light on your problem? What actions did you perform (write complete steps to reproduce)? On which Ubuntu version? Is it related to known [bug with launching pkexec'ed application on Wayland](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1712089)? Please update your question with output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`, `apt-cache policy synaptic`, `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Finding out about `synaptic-pkexec` is easy:

```
w3@aardvark:~(1)$ locate synaptic-pkexec
/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
synaptic: /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -L synaptic | grep -E 'pkexec|man/|READ|doc'
/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
/usr/share/man/pt_BR
/usr/share/man/pt_BR/man8
/usr/share/man/pt_BR/man8/synaptic.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/synaptic.8.gz
/usr/share/man/tr
/usr/share/man/tr/man8
/usr/share/man/tr/man8/synaptic.8.gz
/usr/share/man/fr
/usr/share/man/fr/man8
/usr/share/man/fr/man8/synaptic.8.gz
/usr/share/man/es
/usr/share/man/es/man8
/usr/share/man/es/man8/synaptic.8.gz
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic.policy
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/synaptic
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/copyright
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/README.tasks
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/README.supported
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/README
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/synaptic/changelog.gz
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ file /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Lots of stuff for you to read, including `/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable`, which is short enough to include here:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/usr/sbin/synaptic" "$@"
```

But one question I have: Why, oh why, would you use a tool-in-a-box that you  don't understand?

However, on further reading of your poorly formatted Q, I surmise that you are trying to run `synaptic` from a non-GUI session. `synaptic` is a GUI tool. `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` are command line tools for packages.

Comment: A lot of useless information. Not quite obvious, but I guess the OP wants synaptic and pkexec to present GUI sudo and receives console menu instead which does not work for them.