# Failed running "sudo nautilus", but if I run "nautilus" it runs

Tags: nautilus, 17.10

I can't run `sudo nautilus`, but if I run only `nautilus` in terminal it runs.

And also I can't run **native application** via terminal using `sudo`.

Terminal shows me a warning if I run using `sudo`:

[image]

This pic shows, if I run `nautilus` in terminal it works:

[image]

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w

Comment: Please don't post photos of text - just post your text error messages.  17.10 uses wayland by default unless certain conditions aren't met. If you are using wayland then raised privileges don't have permission to access your gui (only you can - it's you gui!). If you run X there will be no problems.  if you want to understand, try entering `id` from terminal, then compare the result for `sudo id` & you'll note your a different user.