# Running gksu problems in 17.10 Wayland with .desktop file

Tags: sudo, backup, .desktop, wayland

I have two root processes I want to have Desktop Icons for. One is Clam and the other is system backup. These ran fine in 17.04. The Clam one runs fine in 17.10 Wayland but the Root Backup does not although I can manually execute the command from a terminal. At login, *Startup Apps* is configured to run `xhost si:localuser:root`. Here is what the .Desktop Files look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ClamTk
GenericName=Virus Scanner
Comment=Scan for threats...
Comment[en]=Scan for threats...
TryExec=clamtk
Exec=gksu "clamtk /"
Icon=clamtk
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=antivirus;virus;malware;scan;scanner;
Name[en_US]=Root_ClamTk
```

Note the executable is `Exec=gksu "clamtk /"`

Here is the Backup one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=Root_Backups
Comment=Change your backup settings
Icon=org.gnome.DejaDup
Exec=gksu /usr/bin/deja-dup
StartupNotify=true
DBusActivatable=true
Type=Application
Terminal=False
Categories=Utility;Archiving;GNOME;GTK;X-GNOME-Utilities;
Keywords=déjà;deja;dup;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=backup;
Name[en_US]=Root_Backup
```

Again, note the executable is `Exec=gksu /usr/bin/deja-dup`

If I execute `$gksu /usr/bin/deja-dup` from a shell, it works. Running it by double clicking the Desktop icon does not. Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Note: Because the 17.04 version I used had a lot of junk in it and mentioned Unity, I made a new Desktop file by copying the old one from the Applications directory just like I did in 17.04 and, like 17.04, I added the `gksu` manually.

Not a duplicate of the question mentioned as I AM using the xhost command.
It WORKS with clamtk but not deja-dup.

Output of /var/log/syslog when I try and run root Backup .desktop

> Jan 23 16:04:33 John-linux nautilus-deskto[5076]: Nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed Jan 23 16:04:59
>
> John-linux systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs. Jan 23 16:04:59
>
> John-linux anacron[10403]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-01-23
>
> Jan 23 16:04:59 John-linux anacron[10403]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

Comment: It is known bug of wayland see [launchpad bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311).

Comment: @N0bert, unrelated. The fact is I am enabling root in Wayland with  xhost si:localuser:root. It WORKS with  clamtk but not with deja-dup. The gksu prompt does not even come up with deja-dup.

Comment: After double clicking and failing can you check `/var/log/syslog` for error messages?

Comment: See (similar bug 1713313 about pkexec)[https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313 ] too. I don't know authentication back-end of deja-dup and clamtk.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix, I provided syslog output in original question.