# Can't use gksudo to run gedit, error copying .Xauthority

Tags: command-line, gksudo

I have a battery power issue that I'm trying to resolve. One proposed solution involves adding some boot arguments and then removing the battery, but I'm running into trouble on the first step. To add a boot argument, I'm running

```
gksudo gedit etc/default/grub
```

However, I get this response:

```
Error copying '/home/username/.Xauthority' to /tmp/libgksu-0n0AJS': No such file or directory
```

New to Ubuntu and not an advanced user.

Comment: `gksudo gedit etc/default/grub` the command should be `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. ""Error copying '/home/username/.Xautority' to /tmp/libgksu-0n0AJS': No such file or directory" please don't retype error messages; copy/paste the actual message `.Xautority` is not the name it stated: it is at least missing an "h".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit an unfortunate snag, see eg https://askubuntu.com/a/961975/29073. The problem is probably you're using Wayland, and the default permissions aren't set for you to open up a GUI window from the commandline.

I'd skip the GUI method, open a terminal, eg `gnome-terminal` (I use kubuntu and actually use `yakuake`) and do

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit as appropriate, save (ctrl+x, choose yes), then don't forget to

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you *need* to use `gedit` then you can allow root, and any local user, to create windows on your display by doing `xhost +local:` before issuing the `gksudo` command.

Comment: Or you can use `sudo -E gedit /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @psusi does that bypass this problem with Wayland?

Comment: FWIW @psusi that doesn't work for me on Kubuntu with `kate` but gives an error and says you have to set the editor as the sudoedit program and use `sudoedit`. If it works for you - I don't have a standard Gnome based install - then it would be useful as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if `kate` is a native wayland app or not... if it isn't, then it won't work since Xwayland is misconfigured and breaks root X11 applications running under wayland.  `gedit` functions as a native wayland application so it works as long as you have `sudo` preserve the environment ( the -E switch ).