# Apps won't start without sudo first

Tags: server, gui, openbox

So, I've got Ubuntu Server 17.10 running with xorg and openbox and I've got this strange problem that I didnt have with my previous build using bspwm.

The problem is that I can't launch any app inside openbox except XTerm which opens normally. 
But when I start any app with sudo, e.g. `sudo gedit`, it launches normally and any subsequent app will launch normally, even without sudo. So I only need to start one app with sudo and the rest will work just fine.

I get no output when I run them without sudo, no errors or anything so I dont know where to start looking...

Thanks for the help!

P.S. Its running in VirtualBox if it makes any difference...

Comment: Please remember to avoid plain `sudo` with GUI application programs. Use `sudo -H` instead, for example `sudo -H gedit` -- Otherwise the ownership of the configuration files might be modified  (to `root` instead of the normal user ID), and it will make it difficult or impossible to use the program with the normal user ID. See for example this link, [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I usually run them with `gksudo` but I did this for a quick example.

Comment: You can change the ownership, of the whole content in your home directory, back to your user by the command: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME`. Where `$USER` and `$HOME` are environment variables and you can check their values by the command: `echo $USER $HOME`.