# About the disk utility

Tags: partitioning, 17.10, gnome-disk-utility

I've been trying to make partitions in my disk using the disk utility provided by Gnome. I've wasted the whole day yesterday searching this forum, other forums, other websites about HOW to use this utility in partitioning the HDD, but NOTHING... I came out with NOTHING.  All I found was just material about its uses, how to open it and what it does.  But nothing explains HOW to do the partitions.  I don't want to improvise and end up breaking my machine.  Can someone please tell me or even direct me to how I can use this utility to make a partition in my HDD?  My HDD is 1 TB and it's in one single partition. My OS is 17.10.

Comment: You can also make partition by using the app "GParted"

Comment: I read in the reviews of the "GParted" that it's not working with Ubuntu 17.10!!  Have you tried it?

Comment: I think **`gparted`** is easier to use than 'Disks' alias `gnome-disks`. It works in 17.10 and Wayland according to the following link, [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Comment: What is a Wayland?  Sorry, I've sooooo beginner.

Comment: **Wayland** is the new system for the graphical desktop. It is replacing **Xorg**. In Ubuntu 17.10, both are installed and you can select which one to use at the login screen. Click on the 'cog wheel' icon.

Comment: Sorry, I feel so ignorant.  I have no idea what Xorg is, but anyway, where exactly is this cog wheel icon you're talking about?  Can't find any to click on!

Comment: @NermeenHussein See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: I never get this cog wheel when I log in and out!!?? I wonder, is my system different?

Comment: Did you make a fresh install of standard Ubuntu 17.10? Or have you got a community flavour (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ..., Xubuntu? Or did you upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, it's a fresh copy.  Only installed 4 weeks ago.  Clean install.

Comment: Do you boot directly into the desktop (without log in)? Otherwise you *should* get the log in screen with the cog wheel.

Comment: No, I boot directly without any log in.  Directly into the desktop.

Comment: Then I think you will get to the log in screen, if you select **log out**, and then you will see the cog wheel, and you can select between 'Ubuntu' which means using Wayland and 'Ubuntu on Xorg' (which means using Xorg). Try that! I think the system will remember your choice, so that it will be used even after reboot. Check what is used i a terminal window with the command line `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: I tried this already.  I logged out and the only option I get is to put my password and log in again, no cog wheel whatsoever!!  I tried your command at the command line and it gave me: Wayland.  Does this mean I can install "gparted"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

Simply:

Use the command below

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

and then run the troublesome program with sudo like this:

```
sudo -H gparted
```

I tried it and it worked.

Comment: Yes, this is the basic method that works in Wayland :-) But you should use `sudo -H gparted` (Always use `sudo -H` with graphical (GUI) programs. Otherwise your normal user ID's configuration files can be hijacked by 'root'.)

Comment: Ok, so this means.  First I put the command:

xhost +si:localuser:root

Then:

sudo -H gparted

Right??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Or you can create a function `gks` according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978 save it and re-use it, which might be more convenient, if you intend to use elevated permissions with graphics in Wayland often. So please modify your answer to avoid confusing other people.

Comment: @NermeenHussein Either that or issue `xhost +si:localuser:root` in a terminal window and then start `gparted` from the GUI (Win-key, type "gpar..." and click on `gparted`).

Comment: What is a "GUI" please?  Is this a program?

Comment: graphical user interface

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.  Is there a place that shows how I can use "GParted" to partition my HDD?  Because that was my original question!

Comment: Search the internet with the phrase **gparted tutorial** and you will find several useful places. Select one that suits you and enjoy :-)