# copy files from an usb mounted hard drive from a USB boot

Tags: usb, hard-drive

My Ubuntu machine power connector died and I need to take it to repair, but I want to backup my data first. I took out the hard drive and connected it via Hard drive enclosure to another machine which is running Windows. Windows cannot see the drive at all so I booted Ubuntu from USB drive. Then I can see all the files and folders but for a lot of them I do not have access. I tried to do this: "Press Alt+F2 to bring dash command prompt. In that window, type gksudo nautilus. This will open nautilus with root permission." but it doesn't seem to work - when I type in gksudo nautilus it shows an icon with gears and "gksudo nautilus" written underneath but nothing happens when I double-click it.

Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland, you need an `xhost`command line and `sudo -H nautilus` from a terminal window.  There are also other alternatives. See this link, [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Comment: Try downloading gksu first: sudo apt install gksu , then: gksu nautilus . works for versions up to 17.10, not sure about 17.10, now that Sudodus mentions it.