# Accessing Another User's data on same computer(GUI)

Tags: gui, users, user-management

I have two users on my laptop, say user1 and user2.
I want to access user1's data from user2, provided I know the password(I manage both accounts). But I want to use the GUI instead of accessing it by terminal.

I tried using the "Connect to Server" option, but I'm not sure what to type in.

How can I do this?

Comment: Logout, then login as the other user.

Comment: If you 'only' want access to the data, do as suggested by @mikewhatever, login as that user. But if you want to copy files from one user to another user, you should make sure that the user who 'wants' the files has read access to the other user's directories and files. Then you can copy the files (but it will be a waste of drive space).

Comment: Well logging in to user1 has some display issues for some reason,  so I'm not opting for that. And yes @sudodus I want to copy those files, but I want to access it via GUI (simple copy and paste) rather than using terminal. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Yes, you can log in graphically, if you use `xhost`. If in your own computer at home, fine, but in a network with several people, for example at work, it is a security risk. So the general recommendation is to do such things via command lines in text mode.

### Log in graphically from one user to another one

- Log in as `user2` according to your question
- Open a terminal window
- Allow the other user (in your question `user1`) to open windows in your desktop environment

  ```
  $ xhost +si:localuser:user1
  localuser:sudodus being added to access control list
  ```
- Log in as the other user

  ```
  $ su - user1
  Password:
  ```
- If you wish, you can run some text mode commands to check where you are, `pwd`, and who you are, `whoami`.
- Next you can start your file browser or some other graphical program. I'm running Lubuntu, so I start `pcmanfm`. In standard Ubuntu you would run

  ```
  nautilus --no-desktop
  ```

The following screenshot illustrates how it works.

<sup>`LANG=C pcmanfm` makes `pcmanfm` use the default language, US English, instead of my local language.</sup>

[image]

### Copy files

You want to copy files from `user1` to `user2`.

- **If 'personal data'**

  - When logged in as `user1`, check that `user2` has read access to the directories and files, that you want to copy and modify the permissions if necessary. This is possible with the file browser, but I think it is easier to check with the command `ls -l` and modify with the command `chmod`.
  - When logged in as `user2`, open two windows of the file browser and copy/paste from the window, that is 'looking at' `user1` files, to the window 
    that is 'looking at' the `user1` directory, where you want the copies.
- **If system data (configuration data). Risky!**

  - The permissions and ownership of system data files is often very important. This means that you must preserve these properies, if you want them to work.
  - It is a good idea to back up your previous system data before you start using some system data from the other user, particularly when there are problems logging into that user (so some system data are bad).
  - This is relatively easy to do with command lines with

    ```
    sudo rsync -Havn source target
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo rsync -Havn source/ target
    ```

    See `man rsync` for more details, for example the effect of the trailing slash.
- An alternative is to **run the file browser with elevated permissions** (preparing with `xhost` for `root` and running with `sudo -H` or `pkexec` or using some other method, that is considered relatively safe, for example `nautilus-admin`. See the following link,

  [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Nautilus worked like a charm!