# Unable to access Virtual network editor - Workstation 14.1 Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've just installed VMWare Workstation 14 on My PC with OS Ubuntu 17.10.

When attempting to run it via the vmware workstation  (**Edit > Virtual Network Editor**), it asks me for a password and nothing happens.

I tried to launch the Virtual network editor using `sudo vmware-netcfg`. I get prompted for root credentials and then I get this error:

```
pc1@mypc$vmware-netcfg
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
pc1@mypc$sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg  #run as super user:
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
** (vmware-netcfg:14122): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
(vmware-netcfg:14122): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

---

```
root@mypc#/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg   
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000!
(This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000!
(This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
No protocol specified
** (vmware-netcfg:14043): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
(vmware-netcfg:14043): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Wayland ? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-a try running without root / sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed after upgrading my OS to Ubuntu 18.04 and reinstalling vm workstation 14.1.2.

After installing vmware go to: **Shared VM** (right click) **> Permission** and check if you have privilege. You can remove / add users.