# Synaptic Package Manager doesn't launch

Tags: 18.04, synaptic, pkexec

I installed Synaptic in Ubuntu 18.04 without any error. It appears between applications. but when I try to open it I enter the password and do not open.

Results of running `pkexec synaptic` from the terminal:

```
Unable to init server: 
Could not connect: Connection refused (synaptic:3345): 
Gtk-WARNING **: 12:41:48.105: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you run the command `pkexec synaptic` from the terminal?

Comment: yes. (Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
) ((synaptic:3345): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:41:48.105: cannot open display: :0
)

Comment: You're using Xorg not Wayland, right?

Comment: Frankly I do not understand what you mean .. I am a new user in Ubuntu

Comment: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` should return either `x11` for Xorg or `wayland`.

Comment: Previously I download x11

Comment: That's probably the reason why you got the error that Synaptic won't open. x11 is built-in by default, so you don't need to download x11 separately. If you did install x11 separately it will show up in your terminal history. The command `man history` shows how to search your terminal history.

Comment: Completely. What do I do to open up

Comment: I can't tell you that because I don't know what you did, but if you did anything to change x11 the command will show up in your terminal history which saves the last 2000 terminal commands that you ran by default.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much .. I will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

Comment: @karel Retracted, but it is still unclear. Questions to OP (what he uses):  Ubuntu version? Desktop environment? Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: @N0rbert He is using Xorg (I know that from a comment) in Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (I know that from another question). The most informative comment of all is *Previously I download x11* which is possibly a package management issue in 18.04.