# Permanently adding Xhost as root

Tags: command-line, xorg, 17.10

I'm a newbie Ubuntu user. Every time I log in to my OS, I always add:

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

How can I add Xhost to root permanently?

My kernel version is `4.13.0-46-generic`.

I have tried [this suggestion on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_GUI_apps_as_root#Wayland), to edit something in `/etc/pam.d/...`, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please explain why you believe you need this. In modern Ubuntu this is not the best method as it is insecure and exploitable. There are probably better methods to get done what you want. And the xhost command does not need to be run as root since you are the owner of the X session. Still bad but a lot better would be to do this: `xhost + &&
sudo gedit &&
xhost -` you achieve the same for a limited amount of time.

Comment: @Rinzwind i think your right about insecure and exploitable, but i always need it every time to edit .txt.   if i do "xhost + && sudo gedit && xhost -" it's just one time to edit .txt.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to use xhost to edit text files? If you own it `vim file.txt`  otherwise `sudo vim file.txt`. You do not want to use graphical tools to edit txt files from command line since those also tend to change ownership. If you don't like vim, use nano :)

Comment: Not a good idea but see https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w. nano is easier for most new users than vim. `sudo nano text.file`

Comment: @Rinzwind i'm not experience for vim and nano sir, like i do copy and paste. perhaps you have any tricks do it permanently sir?

Comment: @N0rbert I don't used gksu/gksudo sir, i have been try this for permanently Xhost, but this not works to me sir