# with a live session of Ubuntu 18.04 how to access all folders with root previliges those are inside a disk having Ubuntu 18.04 Installed.?

Tags: permissions, 18.04, live-usb, root

I am new to Ubuntu. But interested to know better.
Ubuntu 18.04 was successfully running. I have changed something in the root folder files during some trials, my Ubuntu 18.04 is stuck before gdm shows.

1. I have run live session.
2. I can see all the folders in my disk where Ubunu 18.04 was running successfully.
3. I am not able to delete or copy paste.

How can i get root privileges?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the live session, you can open a terminal window and run commands with the prefix `sudo`, for example

```
sudo copy path2/file1 path2/file2
```

to copy `file1` with root privileges.

In standard Ubuntu you can open a terminal window with the hotkey combination

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

In a live session you need no password to run via `sudo`, but in an installed system, you need the password for your user ID to run via `sudo`.

Comment: @PRATAP, It is possble, but it is easier to give advice with command lines for a terminal window, because it will work in most cases. If you run Xorg, you can try `sudo -H nautilus` and if you run Wayland, you can try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978), but I suggest that you learn using commands in terminal windows.