# xhost: unable to open display "0"

Tags: xorg, display

I have installed /usr/local/stata/xstata-mp as root, permissions 755.

When I try to run this program from a non-root account via the terminal, I get:

```
user@host ~ % /usr/local/stata/xstata-mp
(xstata-mp:8030): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:09:24.384: cannot open display: 0
```

"That's odd," I think, I just know I set `DISPLAY=0` in my .zshrc, "Well, maybe I need to explicitly do so when running this command?" So I try:

```
user@host ~ % DISPLAY=0 /usr/local/stata/stata-mp
(xstata-mp:8201): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:13:28.638: cannot open display: 0
```

**Edit: per @steeldriver 's comment I have also tried DISPLAY=:0**

I have a gander around, and find [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967) which seems promising (although I am not using Wayland, I am on Ubuntu 18.10 and Wayland remains installed). I try the below command as user@host, and as su in an administrative account:

```
user@host ~ % xhost -si:localuser:root
xhost:  unable to open display "0"
```

I get desperate, and try:

```
user@host ~ % DISPLAY=0 xhost -si:localuser:root
xhost:  unable to open display "0"
```

I try other display numbers all to no avail. I think "I am a newb, maybe `localhost` really means [LOCAL USER] and try with the permutations mentioned above.

```
user@host ~ % xhost -si:user:root
xhost:  unable to open display "0"
```

It turns out I *am* a newb, but that didn't help. :)

**How can I make the xhost magic happen so that Gtk doesn't throw a fit and I can just launch my application (as user@host)?**

**EDIT 3-22-2019:**

```
pgrep -a Xorg
3907 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/123/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
7370 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

Comment: The `DISPLAY` variable would usually have the form `:0` rather than plain `0` - also you could check that the X server is running on display `:0` (by `pgrep -a Xorg` for example)

Comment: @steeldriver Please see the output from `pgrep -a Xorg` in my most recent edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason (quite probably having to do with me being an aforementioned newb), although `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`, if I type `who` I see that my display is actually `:1` (?!), so that if I invoke `DISPLAY=:1 /usr/local/stata/stata-mp` the program launches without error.

To reiterate my solution of `unable to open display #`:

1. type `who` and note the actual display number (including a colon if present)
2. for the desired command (e.g., `xhost`, or `/usr/local/stata/stata-mp`), type `DISPLAY=[INSERT NUMBER YOU NOTED HERE] [x COMMAND HERE]`

I will *gladly* upvote and accept another answer which can help me understand this seemingly discrepant behavior.

Comment: This was also my experience!
Do you know why DISPLAY was suddenly incorrect? I am experiencing the issue after upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04, and lots of things stopped working (Google Chrome can't run from the terminal but can be launched indirectly via shortcuts in the applications menu). Minecraft has the same issue. Running MC with DISPLAY changed to :1 fixes it for me. Any ideas on a more permanent fix that isn't hacky?

Comment: Can also report after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 , I have issues with this. 'who' shows me as on ":1" , for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

None of the xauth or xhost schemes allowed root to open the display in Debian 10 (Buster) or Ubuntu 20.04 from a terminal running root via "su" or an application launched using "sudo".

Somebody (I don't remember who) posted (I don't remember where) to add the following line to /etc/pam.d/su and /etc/pam.d/sudo:

session optional pam_xauth.so

It would be helpful if that were (a) easier to find, or (b) that way in distributions.

Comment: somehow I feel there must also be a tweak like this for non-root users since on `focal` I really don't get the x11 authentication to work while it was working very well on `bionic`.

Comment: I added `session optional pam_xauth.so` line in the file /etc/pam.d/sudo file and tested with sudo xeyes. It worked. Only this handle worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `xhost +si:localuser:root`

This tells the xserver you are using (whether on display :0 or :1, or wherever) to accept connections from local users called 'root' - that is, programs with SUID to root, or you did `sudo` in front of.

Answer (score 1):

Runnig a X window under sudo (or as root) typically fails with an `unable to open display ..`.  I have not tried to modify the

`/etc/pam.d/su and /etc/pam.d/sudo`

file, but another small workaround fixes the display (as root) ala this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

X=`xauth list $DISPLAY`
sudo  -- bash -c "xauth add $X && $@"
```

Save it as, say `xsudo.sh` and call it like a normal `sudo` command ala

`> xsudo.sh gparted`

It just adds your per-user xauth cookie to the root-accounts cookies, and hence makes the display work on localhost.