# pkexec hanging in gnome 3.28 & xorg, takes forever to proceed, how to fix it?

Tags: 18.04, synaptic, pkexec, deadlock

After the OS is running for a while, it may trigger for a bug that caused `pkexec` (including any application that use it, including `synaptic`) to hang. This can only be recovered from relaunching OS or gnome-shell.

This is a screenshot that describe this situation:

> ```
> xhost +si:localuser:root
> pkexec synaptic
> ```

[image]

I remember the same error in Manjaro with gnome 3.28, it disappeared in gnome 3.30. How do I backport the fix (if there is any) to Ubuntu 18.04?

**UPDATE 1**

these are my desktop environment:

```
$ export | grep XDG_SESS
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="1"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"
```

...  and synaptics version

```
$ apt-cache policy synaptic
synaptic:
  Installed: 0.84.3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.84.3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.84.3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
peng@peng-ThinkPad-P51s:~$
```

**UPDATE 2:** it appears that it is caused by an unknown bug in gnome authentication agent, as I switched to XFCE and this problem never happens again, so now the problem becomes: how to get rid of the gnome authentication agent?

Comment: Are you running Wayland? What graphical session do you use? Please add output of `export | grep XDG_SESS` to the question. What is the version of Synaptics? Add output of `apt-cache policy synaptic` to the question. Have you read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/961967/66509)? I can't reproduce your issue on clean 18.04 LTS with Unity, Ubuntu and GNOME FlashBack sessions (with all sorts of Xorg and Wayland). Do you have GNOME related PPAs?

Comment: I myself sometimes cannot reproduce it, it only appears after running for a while after resuming from sleep

Comment: When it happens I would check `journalctl -xe` for clues. If system froze after reboot use `journalctl -b-1` and then press `End` key.