# How to login as root in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, login, password, root

For some reasons, I need to run the whole GUI as root. So I tried to login **root** user account from ubuntu. I selected **Not Listed?** option. And I entered username **root** then when I enter the password it says That didn't worked... but that is the correct password for **root** user account.....

Can't I login as **root**??

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, up to date

Comment: Ubuntu is designed so that you should not run as root, but with a normal user ID. Use `sudo program-name` to raise permissions when necessary, but do as much as possible with normal permissions. The reason is simple: avoid severe damage to the operating system by mistake. You can make exceptions, and run `sudo -i` and arrive at the root prompt `#` and get elevated permissions. But please avoid it when possible.

Comment: When i try to open gedit as root using sudo i get something like  _Unable to Open display: Connection refused_ what to do in that case?

Comment: *For some reasons, I need to run the whole GUI as root.* Whatever those reasons are, they CAN'T be good. This is a X-Y problem.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978) may help you run gedit and nautilus with elevated permissions in a good way. Use the following command line: `gedit admin:///path/to/file`

Comment: @sudodus `sudo -H gedit /path/to/file` should be easier. `sudo -H` should be used when starting any GUI app from the terminal CLI.

Comment: @heynnema, Yes for a long time it was like that. But in the new versions of Ubuntu we no longer need -H. Anyway, it is considered safer to use that admin method with gedit, or simply stay with text mode tools with sudo.

Comment: @sudodus In 21.04 `man sudo` still shows -H as a viable option. Do you know what/when the behavior that you describe kicked in?

Comment: @heynnema, See [this post by a forum moderator at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463801&p=14044344#post14044344). I think he will answer if you ask him directly.

Comment: @sudodus I looked at your provided link. TL;DR... I'm not sure it applied to our conversation... but maybe I didn't spend enough time skimming it :-)