# Running Synaptic under WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wayland, synaptic

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL on Windows 11.
I installed the synaptic package manager and tried to run it through `sudo synaptic`, but it gives me this as a result:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to initialize GTK.

Probably you're running Synaptic on Wayland with root permission.
Please restart your session without Wayland, or run Synaptic without root permission
```

How can I run Synaptic with sudo in Ubuntu under WSL?

Answer (score 0):

if `xhost +si:localuser:root synaptic` not working, you probably should login using the *Xorg* session because Wayland does not allow gui applications to run in superuser mode. take a look at this [Unix & Linux answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/877826/1194692)

Answer (score 0):

I initially had almost the same message when attempting to reproduce, and in my case it was due to some experimentation I was doing with Systemd under WSL.  The funny thing was, that Systemd work was in a completely different WSL instance, but it had corrupted the WSLg X11 socket.

As a result, Synaptic was attempting to run using the Wayland socket instead.

Are you using any Systemd script, such as Genie or WSL2Hacks, by any chance? if so, try without it. Remove the Systemd script, exit Ubuntu, issue `wsl --shutdown`, and restart.

Also check:

- Can you run other X11 apps?  Try:

  ```
  sudo apt install xterm
  xterm
  ```

  Does that work?
- `echo $DISPLAY` -- WSL2 with WSLg should automatically set this to `:0`.
- `ls -lah /tmp` -- Does `.X11-unix -> /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix` exist there?  If it doesn't point to `/mnt/wslg/.X11-unix`, then your X11 socket is still not fixed.  `systemd-tmpfiles` does overwrite this, but there could be other reasons.